# UIDatePicker not showing when I click the button

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uidatepicker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UemZh.png)I have a UIDatePicker with a label for showing the date and a button for showing the Datepicker.For the first time when I click the button it is showing the datepicker but and after I set the date and click done button,datepicker is hidden.Then again when I click on the button for showing the datepicker,it doesnt show up.
This is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datepicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnDone;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *selectedDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolBar;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize btnDone,datepicker;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    self.datepicker.hidden = YES;
    self.toolBar.hidden = YES;

    [self.datepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)datePickerChanged:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
    self.selectedDate.text = strDate;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

- (IBAction)show:(id)sender 
{
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                           delay:0.1
                         options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                      animations:^{

                         self.datepicker.hidden = NO;
                         self.toolBar.hidden = NO;


                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];


    self.datepicker.hidden = NO;
    self.toolBar.hidden = NO;


}


-(IBAction)HidePicker:(id)sender{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         datepicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, -250, 320, 50);
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [datepicker removeFromSuperview];
                         [btnDone removeFromSuperview];
                         [_toolBar removeFromSuperview];
                 }];

[self.datepicker removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: Where you are using 'HidePicker:' method?

Comment: in -(IBAction)HidePicker:(id)sender method you have removed the piker form superview thats why you are facing the issue

Comment: how to bring back the view once the button is clicked if its been removed once?

Comment: `[datepicker removeFromSuperview];` it will remove the datepicker from view so you have to create new instance and add to view again. but why you are removing it means go for hide only

Comment: Please use  self.datepicker.hidden = YES; instead of [datepicker removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datepicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnDone;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *selectedDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolBar;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize btnDone,datepicker;

- (void)viewDidLoad {


    self.datepicker.hidden = YES;
    self.toolBar.hidden = YES;
    [self.datepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}

- (void)datePickerChanged:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *strDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datepicker.date];
    self.selectedDate.text = strDate;
}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)show:(id)sender
{
    [self.view addSubview:datepicker];
    self.toolBar.hidden = NO;
    self.datepicker.hidden = NO;
    self.btnDone.hidden=NO;
}


-(IBAction)HidePicker:(id)sender
{

    self.datepicker.hidden = YES;
    self.toolBar.hidden = YES;
    self.btnDone.hidden=YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IBOutlet UIButton       *btnDateSelect;

IBOutlet UIView         *vwMainDatePicker;

IBOutlet UIView         *vwMainPicker;


-(IBAction)dateshowPicker:(id)sender
{
    [self textResingFirstResponder];


    [viewDatePicker setBackgroundColor:viewBackgroundColor];

    viewDatePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, -viewDatePicker.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, viewDatePicker.frame.size.height);
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:vwMainDatePicker];

    vwMainDatePicker.frame = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].frame;


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{

        [scroll setScrollEnabled:NO];


            //  vwDate.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 
        self.view.center.y-self.view.frame.size.height/3

            //       , self.view.frame.size.width, 205);
        viewDatePicker.center =  CGPointMake(vwMainDatePicker.frame.size.width  / 2,

                                             vwMainDatePicker.frame.size.height / 2);

    }completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {

         NSLog(@"Animation is complete");
     }];
}
- (IBAction)doneDatePickerBtnPressed:(id)sender
{

    [UIView  animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        viewDatePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, -viewDatePicker.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, viewDatePicker.frame.size.height);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
         NSString  *datetSelected   = [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
         txtdob.text = datetSelected;
         isDateSelected = YES;
         [vwMainDatePicker removeFromSuperview];
         [scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];

         [scroll setUserInteractionEnabled:true];
     }];
}
- (IBAction)cancelDatePickerBtnPressed:(id)sender
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
        viewDatePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, -viewDatePicker.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, viewDatePicker.frame.size.height);
    }completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         NSLog(@"Animation is complete");
         NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];

         if (isDateSelected)
         {
             // txtdob.text =@"";
         }else{

             txtdob.text =@"";
             isDateSelected = NO;
         }

         [vwMainDatePicker removeFromSuperview];
         [scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];

     }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove this syntax from your code, then it'll work:

`[self.datepicker removeFromSuperview];`